In JSONATA how to add the values
here I have to add price and quantity combined
Excepted output:
price 10+2=12
+
Quantity2+1=3
combing both Excepted output as 12+3=15
(In JSONata how to do sum of the values)
  "Order": [
      {
        "OrderID": "order103",
        "Product": [
          {
            "Price": 10,
            "Quantity": 2
          },
          {
            
            "Price": 2,
            "Quantity": 1
          }
        ]
      }
]


$.Order.Product.(Price + Quantity) ~> $sum()
Playground link: https://jsonatastudio.com/playground/f2c385d1
